Synapse COPY INTO performance with nvarchar(max)
I have an Azure Synapse dedicated pool. I use COPY INTO to read CSV files from Azure blob storage into an existing table. It can consistently load 3Gb / 27M rows in under 10 minutes.
Target table
CREATE TABLE xyz.some_table (
   some_table_id  int      null,
   some_event     datetime null,
   /* snip */
   col_p          nvarchar(256) null,
   col_q          nvarchar(256) null,
   col_r          nvarchar(256) null
)
WITH (
    HEAP,
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
);

COPY INTO
COPY INTO xyz.some_table
FROM 'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/folder'
WITH (
    CREDENTIAL = (IDENTITY = 'MANAGED IDENTITY'),
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FILE_TYPE = 'CSV',
    COMPRESSION = 'NONE',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0X0A',
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
);

Turns out this implementation is incorrect - the source tables are nvarchar(max). So after a year of running well I got truncation errors.
I changed the Synapse target table to also be nvarchar(max).
...
   col_p          nvarchar(max) null,
   col_q          nvarchar(max) null,
   col_r          nvarchar(max) null
...

and it now takes 2 to 3 hours to load the same files that used to take 10 minutes. I redefine these columns from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(4000) and performance is back where it was.
I observe this at scales from 100 to 1500DWc when there is little or no other load on the system. So it seems unlikely to be workload resource contention.
I am familiar with SQL Server internals and how lobs are stored differently to other data types. I have no intuition about Synapse, however, and what may be causing this performance degradation. I'm asking for insights, links or hints, please, as to what's going on here.

For better performance you need to minimize the size of the data type which shortens the row length.
That is, you give the longest character length of a column instead of MAX.
Because when you give MAX it takes maximum storage size of 2 GB
check here.
You can also refer here it is mentioned

When possible, use NVARCHAR(4000) or VARCHAR(8000) instead of
NVARCHAR(MAX) or VARCHAR(MAX).

for better performance.

This is good general advice, I agree. In SQL Server I'd be looking at excessive memory grant or off-row storage being slow for some reason. With Synapse I don't have this same level of intuition. What, specifically, is your hypothesis for my situation and how would I measure this in Synapse?
